# What is an "exhausterator" and what does it do?

Tags: engine-design, turbopump, atlas-rocket-family, saturn-i

I laughed when I first saw the word "exhausterator" mentioned, I scratched my head when I saw it the second time, and I came here after the third.

Besides making me feel like maybe technobabble isn't so far off the mark, the "exhausterator" is a very funnily-named component I keep running across in LR101 and H-1 documentation. What the heck is an exhausterator, what does it do, and why did they name it that? My best guess is that it's a vent**ilator** for the turbopump **exhaust**, but it's clearly not designed to provide film cooling to the nozzle. I also know that LR101 and H-1s had nozzles that terminated in this funky component, so it wasn't film cooling for nozzle extensions either.

Why does the exhausterator exist?

[image]

Comment: Too bad they didn't also use "oxidizerator" and "injectorator"  :-)

Comment: An exhausterator without a turboencabulator?  How in the world would the reflux flow be conflabulationally rotational in this configuration?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've not heard it called that, it is normally called an 'aspirator'. And yet there it is on your drawing :) Perhaps they crunched up 'exhaust aspirator' into one word?

As quoted in this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38191/6944)

> The aspirator prevented the fuel-rich exhaust gases of the gas
>   generator from recirculating into the missile boat tail during flight.
>   Instead, the gases merged into the engine exhaust plume.

Reference: [Stages to Saturn Chapter 4](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/ch4.htm) - The H-1 Engine General Description.

[image]

Image [source](http://heroicrelics.org/info/saturn-i-and-ib/saturn-i-ib-turbine-exhaust/h-1-information-illustration-1-of-2-sm.jpg) (I added the arrow)

Comment: Is this one of those cases where enough people miscalled the name of the part to get its 'unofficial' name on the documentation?

Comment: Another possibility is that the OP's diagram was originally in English with the terminology "aspirator", then got translated around at least a couple of times, and eventually landed back in English as "exhausterator".

Comment: @LeeMosher Maybe, but it sure looks like a classic US 1960s drawing to me.

Comment: Here's an edited  quote from the article http://heroicrelics.org/info/saturn-i-and-ib/saturn-i-ib-turbine-exhaust.html that has the same diagram embedded in it: > However, there was a problem: ... The Saturn's designers settled on a compromise: while the inboard engines would dump their turbine exhaust through the side of the stage's tail unit, the outboard engines would dispose of the exhaust by expelling it through a hollow, open-ended "shell" or aspirator (sometimes called an "exhausterator", especially in the early Saturn documentation) around the base of the thrust chamber.

Comment: @LeeMosher that's all covered in the answer linked in the text above.