# Did the Saturn IB have eight equally spaced fins around its circumference?

Tags: nasa, history, identify-this-object, saturn-i

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41481/12102) to *Saturn V Small Rectangles On S-II Stage* includes images and links related to the [Saturn IB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_IB) rocket. It shows what I think is an unwrapped representation of part of a circumference which proceeds from Fin 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and then Fin 1.

**Question:** Did the Saturn IB have eight equally spaced fins around its circumference? If not what is it that this drawing is showing?

[image]

Indiscriminately cropped from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41481/12102); [Source][2] *APOLLO/SATURN CONSOLIDATED INSTRUMENTATION PLAN FOR AS-204/LM-1*  pp 3-5 & 3-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it did as shown in this drawing.

[image]

[Source](http://www.georgesrockets.com/GRP/Preview/Saturn-IB.html) (annotation mine)

Comment: I'd thought that I was misunderstanding the drawing, and the first images I pulled up all had smoke and fire obscuring the base of the rocket, so I was surprised to see that there really are eight giant fins here! I'll poke around the site to see if there is already an explanation for why this particular rocket has such a huge fin area. or not.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38188/6944 :)

Comment: Ha! Good find! ;-)

Comment: @uhoh probably design heritage of the contractor :) https://justamericanautomobiles.com/images/1961-Chrysler.jpg

Comment: now *that's what I'm talkin' about!*

Comment: They were deservedly proud of it https://assets.hemmings.com/blog/wp-content/uploads//2018/06/35546596_10216911160159239_6078489698735489024_o.jpg

Comment: oh, [now I understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler#Space_boosters) the reference, I didn't really appreciate this connection until now